# How to disable all css from the theme for a specific post type page

Tags: css, wp-register-style

I´m creating a plugin and I need, when the admin is logged in and a `single-{post-type-slug}.php` does not exist, the page `https://my-site/post-type-slug/my-admin-page.php` can be displayed without loading the theme css.

I tried :

```
wp_dequeue_style('screen');
wp_deregister_style('screen');

wp_dequeue_style('style');
wp_deregister_style('style');


wp_dequeue_style('style.css');
wp_deregister_style('style.css');

wp_dequeue_style( 'wpsl-styles' );
```

Inside my Object like this...

```
 add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', array( $this , "remove_style" ), 100000 );

 or

 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this , "remove_style" ), 100000 );


and

public function remove_style(){
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wpsl-styles' );
    //wp_dequeue_style("style");
    //wp_deregister_style("style");
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $style ) :
        echo $wp_styles->registered[$style]->src . "<br/>";
    endforeach;
}
```

Nothing works (Wordpress 5.x) and it´s a system to remove only `style.css`. I would like to find a way for my plugin to remove all styles except for the WordPress admin bar.

Anyone got an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to list all the handles and after that, I chose all css I wanted to keep to do this function :

```
//call in my object
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this , "clean_styles" ), 9999 );

public function clean_styles(){
    wp_debug_log();
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $style ) :
        //List the css src and handle
        //echo $wp_styles->registered[$style]->src . " - ";
        //echo $wp_styles->registered[$style]->handle . "<br/>";
        $handle = $wp_styles->registered[$style]->handle;
        //array of css I want to keep
        $css_exception = [ "wp-block-library", "wp-block-library-theme", "admin-bar" ]
        if( !in_array( $handle, $css_exception ) ){
            wp_dequeue_style( $handle );
            wp_deregister_style( $handle );
        }
    endforeach;
        //echo "<br/><br/>";
    //List the css list I kept
    /*foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $style ) :
        echo $wp_styles->registered[$style]->src . "<br/>";
    endforeach;*/
}
```